# How to add Fast forward button on java (Mp3 player)

Tags: java, android

I want to add a fast forward button on my code but I did not find how.
this is my code I hope someone will help me.

MusicPlayer.java:

```
imagePlaypause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updater);
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);



                }else {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.pausebutton);
                    updateSeekBar();

                }
            }
        });

        new Content().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("downloadlink"));
        textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));


        playerSeekBar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) view;
                int playPosition = (mediaPlayer.getDuration() / 100) * seekBar.getProgress();
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(playPosition);
                textCurrentTime.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()));
                return false;
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i) {
                playerSeekBar.setSecondaryProgress(i);
            }
        });


        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                playerSeekBar.setProgress(0);
                imagePlaypause.setImageResource(R.drawable.playbutton);
                textCurrentTime.setText(R.string.zero);
                textTotalDuration.setText((R.string.zero));
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                new Content().execute(getIntent().getStringExtra("downloadlink"));
                textTotalDuration.setText(milliSecondsToTimer(mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            }
        });

    }
```

I want to add a fast forward button on my code but I did not find how.
this is my code I hope someone will help me.

Comment: Based on your code, you seem to know how to add buttons to the UI. Is your question about adding buttons, or how to implement fast-forward?

Comment: @jscott my question was about how to implement fast forward but I found how. You can find the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found how

```
 if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    int currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mediaPlayer.getDuration()) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                    } else {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                    }
                }
```